# How to trigger USPS address standardization on API address create?

Tags: api, addresses

It looks like addresses created by an API call do not go through the USPS address standardization routine.  Is there a way to trigger the standardization through the API?  Or what is the BAO function call to trigger it directly?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm in the same situation now and struggling to find a fix.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, when you have more reputation you will be able to post comments to follow up.

Comment: I'm aware, but there's only so much I can do in only day, and *develop the reputation to add followup comments* fell to the wayside compared to actually coming up with a workaround. I've since figured out how to handle the address validation, so I guess it's all moot anyways.

Comment: If you have a workaround that do post it - then you'll get some reputation to help next time.